# SQL Server: Most recent attribute set and date from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table of several incomplete records each alluding to a certain customer - customer type (Type), annual purchases (A), customer location (B), secondary contractor (C), frequency (D), etc. These records act as snapshots of imperfect information about each customer and are assigned a year and unique snapshotID (snapID).

My goal is to create a single record composed of the latest non-zero, non-null values of each field (along with the year associated with that snapshotID) per customer and customer type (each customerID may have multiple customer types), and to be blank otherwise.

At different points during my exploration, I believed that the solution had to do with Partition, Subqueries, Pivots, Case, or simple Order By/Group By’s, but I am too much of a novice to make sense of differing use cases.

Sample Data:

```
[custID]    [Type]      [snapID]    [A]     [B]         [C]          [D]        [Year]
1025        InPerson    5           0       (NULL)      Cavs        Weekly      2020
1025        InPerson    6           275     (NULL)      Heat        Weekly      2019
1025        InPerson    7           600     Cleveland   Cavs        (NULL)      2018
7256        Online      8           (NULL)  Akron       (NULL)      (NULL)      2020
7256        InPerson    9           375     (NULL)      Nets        (NULL)      2020
7256        Online      10          400     (NULL)      Thunder     Monthly     2015
7256        InPerson    11          (NULL)  (NULL)      Magic       (NULL)      2014
```

Desired Result:

```
[custID]    [Type]      [A] [AYear] [B]         [BYear] [C]     [CYear] [D]     [DYear]
1025        InPerson    275 2019    Cleveland   2018    Cavs    2020    Weekly  2020
7256        InPerson    375 2020    (NULL)      (NULL)  Nets    2020    (NULL)  (NULL)
7256        Online      400 2015    Akron       2020    Thunder 2015    Monthly 2014
```

Comment: Apologies. I just edited the question. Tagged with SQL Server and SSMS. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This may be done using some nested subquery construct that will be difficult to understand and debug. Therefore, if your platform allows you, I would go another way, using user defined functions.

For the exact syntax, consult your DBMS documentation. I would define functions like

```
create function maxAYear (
@custID int,
@type varchar(...)
)
return select max(Year)
       from your_table
       where custID = @custID
       and @type = type
       and A is not null
       and A <> 0

create function maxA (
@custID int,
@type varchar(...)
)
return select A
       from my_table
       where custID = @custID
       and type = @type
       and year = maxAYear(@custID, @type)
```

and then build my result table as

```
select custID, type, maxA(custID, type), maxAYear(custID, type), ...
from (
    select distinct custID, type
    from my_table
) a
```

I know that some people discourage using user defined functions. But I use them quite frequently without any issues, and they have two advantages:

- They allow a modular design that is easy to understand,
- they are reusable,
- they can be tested separately, which isn't true for nested subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

In standard SQL, you can use `last_value(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*
from (select custid, type,
             last_value(a ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as a,
             last_value(case when a is not null then year end ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as ayear,
             last_value(b ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as b,
             last_value(case when b is not null then year end ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as byear,
             last_value(c ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as c,
             last_value(case when c is not null then year end ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as cyear,
             last_value(d ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as d,
             last_value(case when d is not null then year end ignore nulls) over (partition by custid, type order by year) as dyear,
             row_number() over (partition by custid, type order by year desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5b1794a92a9cd9f78031bb4620d0cb0) is a db<>fiddle.

Your question is tagged "SQL", which refers to standard SQL.   And this is a standard SQL solution. If this doesn't work in your particular database, then ask a *new* question with an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon for going through the trouble, this has been pushing me to my limits. Unfortunately (which I like a true n00b forgot to mention), I am working in SQL Server, instead of Oracle, and the "last_value([column] ignore nulls)" portion of the query is giving me fits. I am in the process of attempting to find the SQL Server equivalent to this command in order to salvage the work you've done here. Thank you again, I'll post when I find a solution!

Comment: @aFellowChucker . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with a clear explanation and appropriately tagged.

Comment: I just edited the question and tagged more appropriately. Thank you again for your assistance.